# What does 'history | grep cp -r ' do?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I typed this commands by mistake in my shell and then my shell was filled with all the text . I don't know what it does .Please someone explain it to me .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't quote the `cp -r` string, the `-r` is getting passed as an argument to `grep`, resulting in it searching for the string `cp` *recursively within the current directory*. If you want to search for literal string `cp -r` within your shell history, you can use

```
history | grep 'cp -r'
```